# How to Program for Leap Motion with Java

Tags: java, leap-motion

I have downloaded everything for leap motion. The software, airspace store, and SDK. I unzipped the SDK folder, but don't know what to do next. Is there a separate SDK or do I import the libraries into Eclipse?

I am running Windows 8, and want to use Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to import the leap jar and provide the correct native dll.

This [link](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/Languages/Java/Guides/Setup_Java.html) has the step by step procedure for setting up a leap project in java.

You need to be signed in to view that link. Hope that helps.

Comment: I can view the link without being signed in!

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you look into the Processing Programming Language. It is not really a new language and it is built on top of Java. In fact, at run time it is precompiled to java code, so any straight up Java you write should run just fine. There are a couple of Java classes that have to do with GUI elements that Processing expands so you can't use those but that's about it. It is really easy to get up and running. Well, as easy as Leap Motion development can be. There is a significant amount of tutorials and resources out there about processing so that helps.